# Chrome: Debug who changes document.location.hash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I'm analyzing a site where the document.location.hash changes after some seconds since page loaded. It seems something asynchronous.
Is possibile to debug who change the hash, via Chrome inspector?

By now I only add a "watch" but is hasn't breakpoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can enable an event listener breakpoint for "hashchange":

[image: Enabling an event listener breakpoint]

As of 2019 Q4, this functionality exists in the "Sources" tab, in a panel titled "Event Listener Breakpoints".

When code now makes a change to `location.href` Chrome would stop at a handler for this event:

[image: The Chrome stopped at a handler for "hashchange" due to a change]

You can now go to the cause using the "Call Stack" panel.

This only works when there's already an event handler for `hashchange`.

Assuming you don't have such an event handler in your code yet, create an event handler like this:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
    debugger;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, wonderful.
I searched it but I didn't found yesterday.

Comment: Hi anyone coming to this post today 2019 Q4 it has now moved to the "Event Listener Breakpoints" panel in the "sources" tab in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Pardon me, but how did this _move_ to such a panel? Look at the first screenshot in the accepted post, it was already located in a "Sources" panel named "Event Listener Breakpoints". Nothing changed.